# how to hide image button in a list view on android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-image

in my app i use list view with image button called buy video. i populate video list from urban air ship. if i press buy button the video is downloaded. 
how to hide image button at a particular position in a list view. i did but the right position and some other position image button also hide. please help me.

i check whether installed(downloaded) or not by the code:

```
if(statusOfProduct.equals("INSTALLED")){
  ....
  buy.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

main code :

```
public class InventoryListActivity extends ListActivity {
 ...........

    public class InventoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Observer,OnClickListener
{ 
     ..........  
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Product product = (Product) getItem(position);
        View view;
            if(statusOfProduct.equals("INSTALLED")){
                Log.e("vocab","if-status");
                Log.e("vocab",product.getIdentifier());
                buy.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // hide right position and some other position image button also.

            } 
}
```

please help me. i do not the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is not clear from your code, this may solve your problem :
In place of

```
buy.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Use

```
((Button) pConvertView.findViewById(R.id.buyButtonID)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: i am getting same problem please tell me some ways.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't totally sure what you were asking, but there is a difference between VIEW.INVISIBLE and VIEW.GONE.  Make sure you're using the right one for your needs.

Comment: my question is how to hide image button at a  particular position in a list view. i did  but the right position and other position image button also hide. that is my problem. i do not know difference between Invisible and Gone. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
yourBtn = (ImageButton) view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
```

and then try this

```
yourBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```